# Refresh the popup contents in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile popup enter some text and refresh the current page using **changePage**. After that open the open it shows in the text box what i enter previously. How to refresh the popup(Please dont suggest empty the textbox value).

The code is:

```
localStorage.setItem("name","tiger");
$(document).on("click","#save",function(){
    $("#openpopup").popup("close");
    localStorage.setItem("name",$("#pText").val());
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1",{
    allowSamePageTransition : true,
              transition : 'none',
    });
});

$(document).on("pageshow","#page1",function(){

if(localStorage.getItem("name")){
    $("#name").val(localStorage.getItem("name"));
}
});
```

Here is the [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcLdkt0w/5/)

Comment: "_Please dont suggest empty the textbox value_". there is no better way than resetting input value than this. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wcLdkt0w/6/

Comment: @Omar thanks for your reply ..i refresh(change) the page even though the popup is not refreshed ..then there is no use in refresh(changepage) in JQM..

Comment: check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wcLdkt0w/7/ `allowSamePageTransition` doesn't _refresh_ page. To refresh the page, you need to use `reloadPage: true`.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/wcLdkt0w/8/

Comment: @Omar check this when use reloadPage:true http://jsfiddle.net/wcLdkt0w/9/

Comment: @Ved i think you misundersatnd my question..

Comment: @Omar i just used your method but for select option ,input,...etc each and every time we need to set(find a suitable method for this) ..

Comment: another option is to wrap all elements in `form` and call `$("#formID")[0].reset();` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n78sdeet/

Comment: @Omar you can add your answer here i will accept....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset all form elements, e.g. `input`, `select`, `checkbox`, etc at once, you need to wrap them in a `form`. And then *reset* the form `$("#formID")[0].reset()` once the *popup* is hidden.

```
$("#popupID").popup({
    afterclose: function () {
        $("#foo")[0].reset(); /* reset form */
    }
}, "close");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n78sdeet/)**

Comment: any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778652/not-able-to-close-the-jt-sage-date-picker-after-pick-date