# Not able to close the jt sage date picker after pick date

Tags: android, jquery, date, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my cordova application i use **jt sage date picker(v 1.3.0)** `inside the popup`. Open date picker inside the popup  using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653524/jquery-mobile-date-picker-not-shown-in-popup-field) now the problem **after selecting the date the datepicker is not able to close.**

```
 <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
```

In browser it is working fine but in my device(nexus 7) not working.

Here is the [FIddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zV3jU/1/)

**EDIT:**

Now i noted another one problem when chaging the date or month in picker then again it come to the current date or month

Comment: The datepicker isn't closing or the popup? I've tested it on iPad, datepicker is closing on "set date".

Comment: @Omar the date picker is not closing..console also doesn't display error logs..